# Can I add a custom application to the sidebar in Google Docs/Sheets/etc

Tags: google-apps-script, gsuite-addons

Following the example code on https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/cats-quickstart, I've been able to create a GSuite add-on that can be used on the Calendar/Drive/G-mail pages. The similar sidebar (ie. one containing Calendar/Keep/Tasks) in Docs, Sheets, etc... does not have my app icon.

My manifest file looks like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "STABLE",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Test",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png",
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "drive": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: In Google Docs and Google Sheets the sidebar is just a dialog. You can build custom applications in them with the [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) and [ClientToServer Communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Is your application working as expected, except for the icon being not shown?